# Reading powershell objects returned by Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: json, powershell

I am having trouble using `Invoke-RestMethod` in PS and retrieving the results...

here is my code:

```
$request='https://sandbox.api.dell.com/support/assetinfo/v4/getassetwarranty/SERVICETAG?apikey=APIKEY'
Invoke-RestMethod $request |
Select $request.ServiceTag
```

The JSON returned by the DELL API call looks like this:

```
{
"AssetWarrantyResponse": [
{

  "AssetHeaderData": {
    "BUID": "202",
    "ServiceTag": "XXXXXXX",
    "ShipDate": "2017-12-04T18:00:00",
    "CountryLookupCode": "UK",
    "LocalChannel": "ENTP",
    "CustomerNumber": "NNNNNN",
    "ItemClassCode": "OB002",
    "IsDuplicate": false,
    "MachineDescription": "Latitude 7480",
    "OrderNumber": "123456789",
    "ParentServiceTag": null
  },
  "ProductHeaderData": {
    "SystemDescription": "Latitude 7480",
    "ProductId": "latitude-14-7480-laptop",
    "ProductFamily": "Laptops",
    "LOB": "Latitude",
    "LOBFriendlyName": "Latitude"
  },
  "AssetEntitlementData": [
    {
      "StartDate": "2017-12-04T18:00:00",
      "EndDate": "2020-12-05T17:59:59",
      "ServiceLevelDescription": "Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis (Consumer Customer)/ Next Business Day Onsite After Remote Diagnosis (Commercial Customer)",
      "ServiceLevelCode": "ND",
      "ServiceLevelGroup": 5,
      "EntitlementType": "INITIAL",
      "ServiceProvider": null,
      "ItemNumber": "123-12345"
    },
    {
      "StartDate": "2017-12-04T06:00:00",
      "EndDate": "2025-12-05T05:59:59",
      "ServiceLevelDescription": "Dell Digitial Delivery",
      "ServiceLevelCode": "D",
      "ServiceLevelGroup": 11,
      "EntitlementType": "INITIAL",
      "ServiceProvider": null,
      "ItemNumber": "525-10302"
    }
   ]
  }
],
"InvalidFormatAssets": { "BadAssets": [ ] },
"InvalidBILAssets": { "BadAssets": [ ] },
"ExcessTags": { "BadAssets": [ ] },
"AdditionalInformation": null
}
```

I need to get several values from that JSON response, I tried using `ConvertFrom-Json` with `|Select ServiceTag, SystemDescription, EndDate` by following the advice in [MS TechNet Scripting Guy: Playing with JSON and PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/10/08/playing-with-json-and-powershell/)

But couldn't get values for ServiceTag, SystemDescription, EndDate (they were blank) - eventually we need to run this in a script for nearly 1500 computers in blocks of 80 at a time and update a database

So where am I going wrong here?

I did try something like `Invoke-RestMethod $request |
Select $request.AssetHeaderData.ServiceTag` but had no luck

Comment: If I copy-paste your JSON, and do `$o=(Get-Clipboard | ConvertFrom-Json) ; $o.AssetWarrantyResponse.AssetHeaderData.ServiceTag` I get back `XXXXXXX`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: that's because I replaced my service tag with X's ...

Comment: Yes, but it demonstrates the basic approach works: I can get the service tag value with my code, so the question is why yours can't. If the tag is actually blank in the JSON itself, your issue is with Dell, not the code extracting the value.

Comment: if I run the correct URL in a browser, I get valid JSON back with the values

Comment: @JeroenMostert: how do I get the `Get-Clipboard` cmdLet to work in PS?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell 5, where `Get-Clipboard` is built-in. Modules like PSCX were necessary for earlier versions of PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$req = Invoke-RestMethod $request
$warranties = $req.AssetWarrantyResponse.AssetEntitlementData[0]
$dellasset  = $req.AssetWarrantyResponse.productheaderdata
```